# School bus binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Of the pupils in a school, 30% travel to school by bus. From a sample of 10 pupils chosen at random,

(i)  what is the probability that only the first three travel by bus?

(ii) what is the probability that the 8th pupil is the 3rd pupil who travels by bus?

My answer using graphic calculator for part (i):

P(X ≤ 3) = Binomcdf (10, 0.3, 3) = 0.65 (3s.f)

actual answer for part (i) is 0.00222. [why is that so?]

I am not too sure how to do part (ii).

Answer (score 1):

For part (i), presumably the wording is meant to be asking "What is the probability that students 1, 2 and 3 travel by bus and the rest do not?"

In which case, you've made two errors:

1. Your binomial probability is calculating the probability of 0, 1, 2 or 3 students travelling by bus, not 3 exactly.
2. The binomial probability doesn't care about *which* 3 students are travelling by bus.

Instead, you need to work out the probability that those three specific students are the ones travelling by bus.

For part (ii), student 8 is the 3rd to travel by bus when the group of students 1 to 7 contain exactly 2 students travelling by bus, and student 8 *also* travels by bus (notice that if students 1 to 7 contain more or fewer than 2 bus-takers, then student 8 can't be the 3rd, and likewise if they don't travel by bus then surely they aren't the 3rd to do so). Can you express that as a probability? As a hint, *this* one probably could use a binomial probability in it.

Comment: Hi, for part (i), I have used P(X ≤ 3) - P(X =0) = 0.621, this still doesn't get to the answer of 0.00222.

Comment: You shouldn't be using binomials at all for part (i), and you're still not calculating the right probability. What's the probability that student 1 travels by bus? What's the probability that student 2 travels by bus? What's the probability that students 1 and 2 *both* travel by bus?